# ImportError: cannot import name DateRange

Tags: django, pip, psycopg2

I am setting up the new Django project with PostgreSQL as a backend . I am using the pip to install the packages . Following are the requirements are install in new environment.

```
Django==1.9
argparse==1.2.1
djangorestframework==3.3.3
psycopg2==2.6.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

I don't know where I made mistakes. please Help me out to configure the new project.please give me step by step procedure to configure the new environment.

The error stack is

```
from psycopg2.extras import DateRange, DateTimeTZRange, NumericRange
ImportError: cannot import name DateRange
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my@box:~ mkvirtualenv env
(env)my@box:~ pip install -r requirements.txt
(env)my@box:~ django-admin startproject proj
(env)my@box:~ ./proj/manage.py shell
>>> from psycopg2.extras import DateRange, DateTimeTZRange, NumericRange
>>>
```

Works for me. Can you `import psycopg2` and `import psycopg2.extras`?

Comment: Can you import psycopg2 and import psycopg2.extras?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is way too late to the party, but apparently using `psycopg2-binary` worked for me.

This was with Djano `2.2.9` and Djongo `1.3.0` that failed to import `psycopg2` with the following error:

```
traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    main()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line                                                                                                                                                                          
    utility.execute()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute                                                                                                                                                                                            
    django.setup()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    app_config.import_models()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  File "/segnet-webapp/webapp/label/models.py", line 2, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    from psycopg2.extras import DateRange, DateTimeTZRange, NumericRange                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

I'm posting this here since it is one of the very few places that show up when searching for this particular error.

All I had to do was:

```
$(venv) pip install psycopg2-binary
```